# reverse string no loops

Tags: c++, string, reverse

ok so this is what i have but I am getting an error says 'complexReverseString': identifier not found??? where am I going wrong I looked it over to no avail

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    string forward;

    cout << "Please enter a string to see its reverse. (Will display reverse twice)" << endl;
    input.open("information.txt");
    cin >> forward;
    //reverseString(forward, findStringSize(forward)); a function I'm not actually calling
    input >> forward;
    complexReverseString();

    input.close();


}
int complexReverseString(string userInput)
{
    string source(userInput);
    string target( source.rbegin(), source.rend() );
    cout << "The reversed string is " << target << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with **the language** this is about.

Comment: If you cannot see the loop, it doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: @KcNorth: Understanding compilation errors is a vital part of learning any compiled language. Looking at the rest of the questions you have posted today, it is definitely time for you to read [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The StackOverflow community cannot teach you a language or how to program, that is not how this site works, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prototype `complexReverseString()` first before you call it.

Either do it in the source file before the `main` entry-point like this:

```
int complexReverseString(string userInput);
int main() { ... }
```

or do it in a separate header:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_STR_HPP
#define COMPLEX_STR_HPP

int complexReverseString(string userInput);

#endif /* COMPLEX_STR_HPP */

/* int main.cpp */
#include "complex_str.hpp"

int main() { ... }
```

Secondly, you forgot to pass a parameter to the function:

```
 complexReverseString( /* parameter here */ );

 e.g
 complexReverseString(forward);
```

Thirdly, since you did not change the string in `complexReverseString()` I suggest taking a `const` string, and perhaps a reference to the string:

```
int complexReverseString(const string& userInput);
```

Comment: FYI, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c

Comment: @Baz1nga FYI , prototyping is good practice. And should _always_ be used in modern code.

Comment: again good to know.. but the problem here was something else and you have updated your answer to address the main prob..

Comment: have not learned how to use headers yet in this class :(

Comment: used complexReverseString(forward); so it ask for user input instead of havin a const

Comment: @KcNorth You used protoypes in "Function 4" in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273921/multiple-functions#comment13214968_10273921).

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the parameter to the method? as your method expects a parameter of type `string` else you need to overload it .. It is currently failing cos it is looking for a function definition `complexReverseString()`

change your code to

```
complexReverseString(forward);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to reverse a string or any other container without an explicit loop in C++ is to use reverse iterators:

```
string input;
cin >> input;
// Here is the "magic" line:
// the pair of iterators rbegin/rend represent a reversed string
string output(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
cout << output << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, the compiler reads the source code from top to bottom. If you use a method before the compiler reads it (ex. when the method is defined on the bottom, and you're using it in `main()` and `main()` is at the top), the compiler will not run through all source/header files in your project/folder until it finds the method or have gone through all files.

What you need to do is either prototype your method, or define it at the top.

A function prototype is basically a method header, used to inform the compiler that the method will be found somewhere else in the source.

Prototype:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <fstream>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// DEFINE PROTOTYPES BEFORE IT'S CALLED (before main())
int complexReverseString(string);

int main()    
{    
    // your main code
}    

int complexReverseString(string userInput)    
{    
    // your reverse string code
}
```

Prototyping will allow you to see the methods and method headers more easily.

Or define `compledReverseString()` at top:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <fstream>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// DEFINE METHOD BEFORE IT'S CALLED (before main())
int complexReverseString(string userInput)    
{    
    // your reverse string code
}

int main()    
{    
    // your main code
}
```

Either one of these styles will yield the same results, so it's up to you to decide which one you want to use.

Aside from this, when you called `complexReverseString()` in main, you forgot to pass its parameters, which should be `forward`. So instead of `complexReverseString()`, it's `complexReverseString(forward)`

Comment: sweet didnt know the post went this far down thank you for all of your speedy responces this sight is the best I appreciate all the help